# If Else Statement is not working in Else side using PowerShell

Tags: powershell, if-statement

I use if else in my powershell script.

```
if ($match.Groups.Count) {
    while ($match.Success) {
        Write-Host ("Match found: {0}" -f $match.Value)
        $match = $match.NextMatch()
    }
}
else {

    Write-Host "Not Found"
}
```

in the if side, it works, but in the else side, It cannot return "Not Found" . It does not show any error.

Comment: If I try to simulate this code by guessing what I think `$match` contains, the code works for me. If you ever enter that `if` block, you are never going to enter the `else` block no matter how many times you use `.NextMatch()` without a loop outside of the `if/else` or calling this entire code block again separately. If the goal is to assign `$match` somewhere above and expect an output of "Match found: , Match found: ....Not found," it can't happen without entering that code block again on another iteration.

Comment: Even failed match have at least one group: `[regex]::Match('a', 'b').Groups.Count`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[PetSerAl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4003407/petseral), as countless times before, has provided the crucial pointer in a comment:

Perhaps surprisingly, the [`[System.Text.RegularExpressions.Match]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.match) instance returned by the static [`[regex]::Match()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.match) method (or its instance-method counterpart) **contains 1 element in its `.Groups` property even if the matching operation *didn't* succeed**<sup>[1]</sup>, so that, assuming an instance stored in `$match`, **`$match.Groups.Count` *always* returns `$true`**.

Instead, **use the `.Success` property** to determine if a match was found, as you already do in the `while` loop:

```
if ($match.Success) {
    while ($match.Success) {
        "Match found: {0}" -f $match.Value
        $match = $match.NextMatch()
    }
} else {
    "Not Found"
}
```

<sup>Note that I've removed the `Write-Host` calls, because  [`Write-Host` is generally the wrong tool to use](http://www.jsnover.com/blog/2013/12/07/write-host-considered-harmful/), unless the intent is explicitly to write *to the display only*, thereby bypassing PowerShell's output streams and thus the ability to send the output to other commands, capture it in a variable or redirect it to a file.</sup>

---

<sup>[1] `[regex]::Match('a', 'b').Groups.Count` returns `1`, even though the match clearly didn't succeed.</sup>